# Modifying Tuples within Lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I apologize for asking such a simple question but I've tried searching this site and still haven't found an answer that works.

I have the following list with tuples within it:

```
[('1', '1', '1', '1'), ('1', '1', '1', '2'), ('1', '1', '1', '3'),
 ('1', '1', '1', '4'), ('1', '1', '2', '2'), ('1', '1', '2', '3'),
 ('1', '1', '2', '4'), ('1', '1', '3', '3'), ('1', '1', '3', '4'),
 ('1', '1', '4', '4'), ('1', '2', '2', '2'), ('1', '2', '2', '3'),
 ('1', '2', '2', '4'), ('1', '2', '3', '3'), ('1', '2', '3', '4'),
 ('1', '2', '4', '4'), ('1', '3', '3', '3'), ('1', '3', '3', '4'),
 ('1', '3', '4', '4'), ('1', '4', '4', '4'), ('2', '2', '2', '2'),
 ('2', '2', '2', '3'), ('2', '2', '2', '4'), ('2', '2', '3', '3'),
 ('2', '2', '3', '4'), ('2', '2', '4', '4'), ('2', '3', '3', '3'),
 ('2', '3', '3', '4'), ('2', '3', '4', '4'), ('2', '4', '4', '4'),
 ('3', '3', '3', '3'), ('3', '3', '3', '4'), ('3', '3', '4', '4'),
 ('3', '4', '4', '4'), ('4', '4', '4', '4')]
```

I want to replace all '1's with another list called 'List1'.  Then I want to change all the 2s to List2 and 3s to List3 etc....in the end I want something like this:

```
[[[List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC], [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC],
  [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC], [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC]),
 ([List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC], [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC],
  [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC], [List2StuffA, List2StuffB, List2StuffC]),
 ([List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC], [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC],
  [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC], [List3StuffA, List3StuffB, List3StuffC]),
 ([List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC], [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC],
  [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC], [List4StuffA, List4StuffB, List4StuffC]),
 ...]
```

and so on where `List1 = [List1StuffA, List1StuffB, List1StuffC]`

I can't seem to get around the "can't modify tuples" bit and I can't seem to change each tuple element of the larger list into a list itself (and get it to stay that way).

I've tried stuff like this:

```
for item in OverallList:
    item = list(item)
    for x in item:
        x = x.replace('1', List1)
        x = x.replace('2', List2)
        x = x.replace('3', List3)
        x = x.replace('4', List4)
```

But when I print out the OverallList nothing has changed.

Any help would be appreciated and again I'm sorry if I simply missed an answer that would work (or applied it incorrectly).

Comment: Can you try and condense your example to something more simple?

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to insert your `item` back into the `OverallList`

```
for idx, item in enumerate(OverallList):
    item = [{'1':List1, '2':List2, '3':List3, '4':List4}[k] for k in item]
    OverallList[idx] = item
```

Comment: yup, this is it.  I think moving the dictionary map external to the list comp makes it clearer though.

Comment: That does it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `item = list(item)` in the for loop, you lose reference to the `OverallList`. That's why any changes to `item` are not reflected in `OverallList`. Same holds true for `x` in `item`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you put 'item = list(item)' that you are no longer referencing the tuple--'item' is a list that is created from the existing tuple that is still in the list. Try printing 'x' in your loop and you should a list with the contents you expect. If that is the case, all you need to do is remove the tuple, change it, and then explocitly put it back in.